# ldap_init and ldap_set_option questions

Tags: c, windows, ldap

I got some questions below using some wldap32.lib functions.
Code

```
#include "winldap.h"

LDAP Connect;
Connect = *(ldap_init(...));
```

1) Is it legal ? Seems so, coz my structure is equial to structure I got using this code

```
LDAP *pConnect;
Connect = ldap_init(...);
```

2)so next

```
ldap_set_option(&Connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, (void*)&version));
```

returns 89 code.

but using

```
ldap_set_option(pConnect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, (void*)&version));
```

Succesed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), it's valid C, it's just not valid for use with the API.

The `LDAP` structure exposed in the `winldap.h` is just the user observable elements of the `LDAP` structure. The library is perfectly entitled to return a pointer to a structure that is significantly larger than the one that's exposed to the user. As a result when you perform the struct assignment only the elements that you know about would get copied, and the rest of this memory would be lost.

So when you attempt to use this, now truncated, copy of the structure you get the `89` error code.

In addition, you would have no way of knowing if the `ldap_init` function failed - when it fails it returns a `NULL` pointer and your program would just die in that case

Comment: You are nice. Thank you for quick response.